# How to detect when NetworkStream finishes on Rx query

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm using Rx to read from a NetworkStream and provide the results as a Hot Observable.
Even if the query works great, I'm not sure if the condition to complete the sequence based on the NetworkStream is the most appropriate. I have cases where the sequence completes and the TcpListener on the other side has not finished or closed the connection.

Here is the query. I will appreciate to get some suggestions about the right condition to safety terminate the sequence:

```
private IDisposable GetStreamSubscription(TcpClient client)
{
    return Observable.Defer(() => {
      var buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

      return Observable.FromAsync<int>(() => {
         return client.GetStream ().ReadAsync (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      })
      .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
      .Select(x => buffer.Take(x).ToArray());
    })
    .Repeat()
    .TakeWhile(bytes => bytes.Any()) //This is the condition to review
    .Subscribe(bytes => {
        //OnNext Logic
    }, ex => {
        //OnError logic
    }, () => {
        //OnCompleted Logic
    });
}
```

Just to be clear about my question, I need to know the best way to detect when a Network Stream is completed on the other side (because of a disconnect, an error, or whatever). Right now I'm doing it by invoking ReadAsync until no bytes are returned, but I don't know if this is completely safe.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Can you please post code that compiles?

Comment: I just edited the code removing the unuseful pieces and making it compilable

Comment: Per the MSDN documentation: The result value can be less than the number of bytes requested if the number of bytes currently available is less than the requested number, or it can be 0 (zero) if the end of the stream has been reached.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but I don't know if that condition could happen only and if only the end of the stream has been reached or if there is any other circumstance on where the Read could return 0 bytes even when the stream has not been finished. I've read in some other places, that there is no clear way to be 100% sure of this.

Comment: I don't think you should rely on the ReadAsync to see if you read everything that was transmitted. I would rather suggest that you use some kind of protocol that you can parse to see if you received all the required data.

Comment: You can be sure that 0 means that the socket will not be returning any more data. The bigger issue with your code is that you're treating the length parameter as an *exact* value, though it's actually just a *maximum* value. Stream implementations can return less than the maximum specified, so if you want to fill homogenously-sized buffers, then you'll have to loop while the return value is greater than 0 *and* the number of bytes read so far is less than the desired length.

Comment: Thanks @DaveSexton. I don't know if I got your point, but I think that's why I'm doing .Select(x => buffer.Take(x).ToArray()). What I do there is getting from the buffer, just the number of bytes returned by the stream.ReadAsync method. Then I loop the observable sequence until the ReadAsync doesn't return any more bytes, which I'm interpreting as the socket is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
private IDisposable GetStreamSubscription(TcpClient client)
{
    return Observable
        .Defer(() =>
        {
            var buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            return Observable.Using(
                () => client.GetStream(),
                st => Observable.While(
                    () => st.DataAvailable,
                    Observable.Start(() =>
                    {
                        var bytes = st.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        return buffer.Take(bytes).ToArray();
                    })));
        })
        .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
        .Subscribe(bytes => {
            //OnNext Logic
        }, ex => {
            //OnError logic
        }, () => {
            //OnCompleted Logic
        });
}
```

Note that this safely disposes of the stream and concludes when there is no longer any data available.